# Do PySpark DataFrames have a "pipe" function like in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

For example in Pandas I would do

```
data_df = (
     pd.DataFrame(dict(col1=['a', 'b', 'c'], col2=['1', '2', '3']))
     .pipe(lambda df: df[df.col1 != 'a'])
 )
```

This is similar to R's pipe `%>%`

Is there something similar in PySpark?

Comment: I don't think so. At the least, it wouldn't be a great method to use. In PySpark you have your DataFrame distributed across multiple servers. If there was a method that behaved like Panda's pipe, it would need to gather the data from all servers into a single one, and then call the lambda function. Why do you want to use `pipe`? Do you want to create a new column? Add new ones? Make transformations or aggregations over rows/groups/the whole dataframe?

Comment: @MkWTF At this point I really just want to rename columns. That's it.

Comment: You have multiple ways of doing that, [check this site](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-rename-dataframe-column/#rename-column), is really good to learn spark. I leave the [pyspark docs here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html) too in case you need them.

Comment: @MkWTF I've got a couple of hundred columns and need to rename them in a loop, so in pandas it's a good situation to use something like `pipe(standardize_col_names)`. My main question was around `pipe` which @someshwar-kale answered. Pipelines are the corresponding thing in Spark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, in `pyspark`, you can easily achieve this pipe functionality with help of `pipeline`.

1. convert each of the pipe function into the transformer. There are some predefined transformers that spark provides, we can make use of that also
2. Create pipeline using the transformers
3. Run the pipeline to transform provided dataframe

**`Example: Let's take the example you provided`**

### Input Dataframe to transform

```scala
 val df = Seq(("a", 1), ("b", 2), ("c", 3)).toDF("col1", "col2")
    df.show(false)
    df.printSchema()
    /**
      * +----+----+
      * |col1|col2|
      * +----+----+
      * |a   |1   |
      * |b   |2   |
      * |c   |3   |
      * +----+----+
      *
      * root
      * |-- col1: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- col2: integer (nullable = false)
      */
```

### 1. Convert each of the pipe function into the transformer

for `.pipe(lambda df: df[df.col1 != 'a'])`, we can easily use spark `SQLTransformer`. so no need to create custom transformer

### 2. Create pipeline using the transformers

```scala
 val transform1 = new SQLTransformer()
      .setStatement("select * from __THIS__ where col1 != 'a'")
    val transform2 = new SQLTransformer()
      .setStatement("select col1, col2, SQRT(col2) as col3 from __THIS__")

    val pipeline = new Pipeline()
      .setStages(Array(transform1, transform2))
```

### 3. Run the pipeline to transform provided dataframe

```scala
pipeline.fit(df).transform(df)
      .show(false)

    /**
      * +----+----+------------------+
      * |col1|col2|col3              |
      * +----+----+------------------+
      * |b   |2   |1.4142135623730951|
      * |c   |3   |1.7320508075688772|
      * +----+----+------------------+
      */
```

Comment: @0111001101110000 Have you checked this?

Comment: This has convinced me that pipelines are the best parallel to pandas's pipe functionality. I think I could make my own transformer for my transformations but don't think that will increase the readability of my code which is the main point of the pipe function.

Answer (score 5):

You can define a "pandas-like" `pipe` method and bind it to the DataFrame class:

```
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame

def pipe(self, func, *args, **kwargs):
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)

DataFrame.pipe = pipe
```

Then, you can pass functions to the `pipe` method to apply to the pyspark DataFrame. For instance, suppose that you want to select all the columns from a DataFrame `my_df`, except for the last two, after having changed its columns. You can use `pipe` for this:

```
my_new_df = (
    my_df
    # Perform some operations to add and/or remove columns
    ... 
    # At this point the list of columns is different 
    # from `my_df.columns`
    .pipe(lambda df: df.select(*df.columns[:-2]))
)
```

Answer (score 5):

In PySpark the pipe function is called transform with documentation [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.transform.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.transform)

The behavior is identical to the Pandas pipe operator.

So the example in PySpark would look like

```
data_df = (
  spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame(dict(col1=['a', 'b', 'c'], col2=['1', '2', '3'])))
  .transform(lambda df: df.filter("col1 != 'a'"))
)
```

Comment: Just noting that `transform` was implemented in Spark 3.0

Comment: Here's a [currently working link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.transform.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.transform) to the `DataFrame.transform` docs.

Comment: [pyspark.sql.DataFrame.transform](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.transform.html?highlight=transform#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.transform) only takes and returns a Dataframe, whereas extending Dataframe with the pipe function from @luiz-otavio-v-b-oliveira can also take any arbitrary arguments.